# Character encoding problem with decryption in PHP from C#

Tags: c#, php, encryption, utf-8, character-encoding

I think I've got a good one for you.

I've got some C# code that encrypts and decrypts strings. It looks something like this :

```
    public static string EncryptString(String toEncrypt, String key)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Encrypting string: " + toEncrypt + "&key:" + key);
        Rijndael AES = Rijndael.Create();
        AES.KeySize = 128;
        AES.BlockSize = 128;
        AES.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        AES.Key = Hasher.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
        ICryptoTransform crypto = AES.CreateEncryptor(AES.Key, AES.IV); 
        byte[] txt = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( HEADER + toEncrypt);
        byte[] cipherText = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(txt, 0, txt.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);;
    }
```

When I encrypt or decrypt in C# it works like a charm. In php I have a decryption algorithm that looks like this:

```
    if($msg!= "" && $key != "")
    {           
        $msg = parseMsg($msg);
        mcrypt_get_key_size ( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,  MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, md5($key,true), base64_decode($msg),MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);      
        $headerLoc = strpos($decrypted,$correctHeader);         
        /*$decrypted = str_replace($correctHeader,"",$decrypted);
        for($x = 0; $x < 31; $x++)
        { 
            // an attempt at getting rid of control characters
            $decrypted = str_replace(chr($x),"",$decrypted);
        }*/
    }
```

The commented out code is just some of the attempts I've made to get the string decoded correctly. The strange part, is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't even without strange characters.

**For example:**

Herp Derp with key: Red works

Message Herp Derp with key swordfish does not work.

Long messages with the key red do no work.

No message with key swordfish works.

**Could that mean that the length of the message key is part of the problem?**

I have ensured that the message and the key are correctly transmitted between the php and the C# it is definitely a problem with the encoding/decoding, and based on the garbage that's spit out I think it has to do with **UTF8 encoding**.  I suspect the **padding mode** as a possible culprit as well, any ideas? **Edit: I didn't notice the 1 or 2 missing pluses that would foobar the whole string, Sorry Stack  :\ ***

Does anyone know how to fix it?

**Edit** After changing to key size, no strings work.
With message Herp Derp and password red, php outputs decrypted as .�ʇ'y-�US2~h\�0�nAZ=�\2/�����|�a���R�`�/������nY�<[B�NB�@�M_f�E��>7�. Does anyone know what character encoding that might be?

Comparing bytes of just encrypted cypertext in C# and just decrypted PHP, I get
C#

php      and then                    c#

[image]

Which would indicate the mcrypt call is not working, but how would I fix it?

**Edit** I have changed the packing mode to zero's, in an attempt to further simplify the problem.

**Solved** I'll post the solution shortly.

Comment: *Please* don't use `ASCIIEncoding.UTF8` - it's like saying `JpegEncoder.Png`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet You can blame MSFT for that, I didn't name those classes Microsoft did.

Comment: Well, I can blame MSFT for *allowing* you to do it (referring to a static member of a base class via a subclass explicitly) - but using `Encoding.UTF8` would be a lot more sensible. No-one's *forcing* you to use `ASCIIEncoding` to create confusing code.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, I'll edit the post and my own code accordingly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm having trouble following you IV here.

Comment: Would it be easier to understand if I removed all the old code comments? I left them there in order for you to be able to see a small amount of the things I've tried. And would some of the output be useful?

Comment: @Henk Holterman I don't need to explicity create the IV because I am using ECB mode.[1](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ECB_Mode) [2](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php)

Comment: Are you sure about `AES.KeySize = 256` ? I think you are using a 128 bit hash on both sides.

Comment: @Henk Holterman When I change the size the entire crypto api breaks in c# as well, but you are correct in that I am using a 128 bit hash.

Comment: @Henk Holterman Actually it still works with 128, but the php side still fails in the same ways.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Sorry, if I seemed disrespectful or ignorant, if your still attempting to answer my question is there any more information I can add/ any other ways to make my question more clear?

Comment: @Shane: I wasn't looking at it, to be honest - because I'm pretty sure the problem *is* with converting the raw binary output of the decoding into a string by performing UTF-8 decoding, and I don't know how PHP handles that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Okay, Thank you for your help, My question was downvoted so I'm just attempting to make it better. I've tried numerous of the php convert methods, including iconv and utf8_encode, but none seem to work. I want to be able to do decryption from the browser, would you suggest CGI + C#?

Comment: @Shane: Certainly using ASP.NET (possibly MVC) will work pretty easily... but there may well be an appropriate way to do it in PHP, which hopefully someone else will come up with. I dislike languages which blur the distinction between text and binary data :(

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks for your help, apparently even Mcrypt is failing, which leads to me to believe the padding mode is the heart of the problem.

Comment: Instead of looking at the decrypted text, first compare the ciphertext with the PHP result of parseMsg() and base64_decode(). Same for the bytes of the key.

Comment: also, make sure you aren't corrupting it with that str_replace line.  For example: if $correctHeader is "\0" you're going to FUBAR the message

Comment: @Henk Sorry for my poor naming, that image is comparing $decrypted as it is created with with the mcrypt_decrypt call, and ciphertext before it is converted to base 64. I have checked that $msg after parsemsg == convert.tobase64string(ciphertext)

@Tremmors based on the image output, it gets messed up even before the header replace

Comment: I have a feeling it is that for loop to remove control characters at the end.  What does $decrypted look like before that?  Were there control characters in the plaintext before it was encrypted?

Comment: @Tremmors @Henk Holterman I commented out the loop and the strip, still no good.

Comment: Does anyone know of a tool for string checking? the base 64 encoded strings are very long, maybe they are very close but not exactly the same?

Comment: @Henk Holterman @Tremmors I think I've gotten to the root of the problem, thank you tremendously for your help. When checking the long base 64 strings I was using for both messages, I checked with one of the few strings that worked, and assumed that all the strings where the same. On subsequent tests I would see both strings, but not notice they one or two character difference, it seems that +'s were getting stripped out, not by my parsemsg, but as part of the post that sends the string to the php. I'm not completely sure this is the issue, but it seems very likely at this point.

Comment: @Hen Holterman @Tremmors More specifically the string would get url encoded, changing spaces to +'s, and then decoded changing those +'s back to spaces, and parsemsg removes spaces, as they shouldn't exist in a base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this same problem a while back, my source was being corrupted by "something" and later discovered it was the string functions. `strpos` is not UTF8 friendly, the mere use of this function changes your character encoding. As a solution replace the

```
 # this line I suspect is your culprit, the mere inclusion of it is corrupting your data
 # php defaulted string functions are ASCII, even if you change your character set PHP 
 # changes it to ASCII
 $headerLoc = strpos($decrypted,$correctHeader);
```

with

```
 #this works in most cases it did not work for me, it may work for you
 $headerLoc = mb_strpos($decrypted,$correctHeader,0,mb_detect_encoding($decrypted,"auto"));
```

or

A blog post on how I managed to work around this using the excellent [PHP UTF8 lib](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/). What this lib does is convert everything to unicode then you can work on it from there. It might be cumbersome in this instance so try to get the above going.

[Hack your own Utf8 ready String functions from Unicode](http://tass.skoudros.com/php-substr-and-utf8-compatibility)

I found it a little annoying that there was no mention of this anywhere on the PHP site, I seem to remember having this issue quite a few times in the past.

Resources

[PHP mb_strpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) | 
[PHP strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it turns out the base 64 encoded string has +'s, The +'s that were already there  when url encoded were not being escaped, and when the string was decoded the +'s were replaced with spaces. **There is a bug in the post url-encode mechanism? I say this because although spaces are encoded as +, if you have a + already, shouldn't it encode with an escape character? **

Either way, I remove spaces in parseMsg, and what results is a string that looks incredibly similar to, but is not exactly the same as the one output from the php. There was actually no problem with the encoding of the output, and so far utf8 encoding has not been necessary, although that is probably because it has not been tested rigorously enough.

Comment: Ok, I have spent many hours trying to fix utf8 issues, I know the pains of working through it. Only a few weeks ago that I gave myself the goal of working through a few PHP/utf8 anomalies. What I worked out was the return values from most of the string functions like strpos where always in ascii. Under normal circumstances this is fine, PHP is capable to turn it back to utf8. When you start using double byte characters everything goes wrong. Glad you solved it.

Comment: Thanks again for taking the time to try and solve my problem... I should have taken even more seriously one of the golden rules of debugging, check your inputs.